# Graph theory Proof, complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show the following:
If we have a simple graph with $12$ vertices, and every set of $9$ vertices contains a $K_5$ (a complete graph with $5$ vertices), show that the graph contains a $K_6$

I tried counting edges and using Turan's theorem, but it didn't work. 
Do you have other ideas?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h495526p2782084

Comment: I didn't know this post existed, thank you!